# Razor skipping nested foreach loops

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

In my database I have a string of child tables. In a razor view I am trying to loop through the ultimate parent and then filter a collection a few levels down.

I have got it to work using the following extract:

```
@foreach (var artist in Model)
{
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => artist.ArtistName)
        </td>
    </tr>

    foreach (var album in artist.Albums)
    {
        foreach (var song in album.Songs)
        {
            if (song.SongPlays != null)
            {
                foreach (var songPlay in song.SongPlays)
                {        
    <tr>
        <td>
             @Html.DisplayFor(a => songPlay.PlayTime)
        </td>
    </tr>
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The issue with this is that I cannot sort the whole child collection by PlayTime. To solve this I then tried to get it working by skipping out the preceding foreach loops using:

```
    foreach (var songPlay in artist.Albums.SelectMany(a => a.Songs.SelectMany(b => b.SongPlays)))
    {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(a => songPlay.PlayTime)
        </td>
    </tr>
    }
```

This seems to work without the filter applied in the controller action, but returns a null result when the filter is applied. I have tried checking in the view if the result is null, but I could not  get this to work - something like:

```
if (artist.Albums.Select(a => a.Songs.Select(b => b.SongPlays)) != null)
    {
        foreach (var songPlay in artist.Albums.SelectMany(a => a.Songs.SelectMany(b => b.SongPlays)))
        { ...
```

I still get a null result, so I am presuming that the null check is not doing what I was hoping it would do.

So if anyone can give me some guidance either on whether this approach is sensible and if I can do a null check on a grandchild collection somehow, or if there would be a better approach, it would be very much appreciated.

Comment: why you don't do this artist.Albums.First().Songs.Select(b=> b.SongPlays)

Comment: @ Overmachine - thanks for replying. I tried using this in the if null check statement but did not have any luck. I think I see what you are trying to do here though. In effect I need to check each Song to see if it has a collection of SongPlays or not, whereas I think your statement checks the first Album?

Comment: It's incredible what people end up in their views with just because they don't use view models.

Comment: Darin - How would you approach using ViewModels without using logic in the view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure I get you right. As far as I understand you need to filter null items and second code sample in your question is ok in terms of orderting. In that case, you may add `Where` clause to selection:

```
foreach (var songPlay in artist.Albums.SelectMany(a => a.Songs.Where(b => b != null).SelectMany(b => b.SongPlays)))
{
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(a => songPlay.PlayTime)
        </td>
    </tr>
}
```

Comment: Hi Dima, thanks for replying. Apologies if I have not articulated the problem in a clear manner - I imagine that is in part due to lack of experience. The issue is that each Song may or may not have a collection of Song Plays, and if there is not a collection, then the the foreach(var songPlay...) returns a nulls exception. Therefore I need to check whether the collection exists in the first place before running the foreach statement.

Comment: Right. I have update filtering, assuming Songs with empty SongPlays ollections are out of your intereset.